# Azure : appsettings.json variable substitution in AzureRmWebAppDeployment task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

In my azure pipeline I used to substitute variables in appsettings.json file the following way :

1. My appsettings file defines variables with token values

   ```
    {
     "AzureAd": {
     "Instance": "__AAD_Instance__",
     "Domain": "__AAD_Domain__",
     "TenantId": "__AAD_TenantId__",
     "ClientId": "__AAD_AuthorPortalApi_ClientId__"
    }
   ```
2. In the release, pipeline variables are defined

[image]

3. A tokenizer task runs at the beginning of the release pipeline and substitutes the tokens with the correct value.

**Note that some variables are similar across different applications**. For instance above I have two applications (AuthorPortalApi and FileApi) that both have a AzureAD ClientId, so I must include the name of the application in the token in order to replace it with the correct value.

This all works really well but now I am changing to use YAML release pipeline. The only difference is that now the variables are defined in a dedicated YAML file:

```
  variables:
     - name: AAD_FilesApi_ClientId
     value: some value
```

I could keep it this way. But I have noticed that the task for deploying azure webapp `AzureRmWebAppDeployment` provides a way to do variable substitution in appsettings.json:

```
  - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy my api'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my sub'
    WebAppName: 'my-api'
    packageForLinux: '$(workFolder)/my-api.zip'
    JSONFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

In a variable yaml file, I have defined my variables like this:

```
variables:
- name: AzureAd.ClientId
value: some value
```

**It works, but  like I said above, if two applications have the same json structure in appsettings.json, then how do I differentiate them to replace by the correct values ?**

I have seen the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution-example), but it does not show how to define the variables in a YAML template.

Answer (score 1):

> if two applications have the same json structure in appsettings.json, then how do I differentiate them to replace by the correct values ?

We could create two **job** template yaml for the pipeline with different variables.

Template `AuthorPortalApi.yml`:

```
jobs:
- job: AuthorPortalApi
  variables:
    AAD_AuthorPortalApi_ClientId: xxx
```

Template `FilesApi.yml`:

```
jobs:
- job: FilesApi
  variables:
    AAD_FilesApi_ClientId: xxx
```

You could check the document [Define variables:Variable scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#variable-scopes) for some more details.

On the other hand, we could also just use one task template with [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script):

```
parameters:
- name: ClientId
  displayName: AzureAd.ClientId
  type: string
  default: Vlaue_AAD_AuthorPortalApi_ClientId
  values:
  - Value_AAD_FilesApi_ClientId
  - Value_OhterThings_ClientId

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: build
  pool: 
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - script: echo The value is ${{ parameters.ClientId }}
```

Select the value when we queue the pipeline or use the default value `Vlaue_AAD_AuthorPortalApi_ClientId`:

[image]

The test result:

[image]

**Update:**

If none of the above methods are suitable for you, then the method I can think of is to use template parameters, but this method requires us to find a condition to pass different parameters to the template:

```
jobs:
- template: ClientId.yml 
  parameters:
    ClientId: AAD_AuthorPortalApi_ClientId
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['xx.xx'], 'xx'))

- template: ClientId.yml
  parameters:
    ClientId: AAD_FilesApi_ClientId
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['yy.yy'], 'yy'))
```

Check this document [Job, stage, and step templates with parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#job-stage-and-step-templates-with-parameters) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think this will be acceptable for me though. Method 1 involves creating templates per application. I don't want to do that and I want to keep templates per application type instead (webapi, class library, etc..) Method 2 is not good either because they are two many variables in the appsettings. It would make the pipeline unmanageable.

Comment: @Sam, I have provided one more method, please check if updated answer helps you.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late reply but I had to switch to other priorities on the project. I'll try to take a look at it this week but in any case I will mark this as the answer as soon as I have tested it. thank you.

Comment: What about this issue?  Have you have time to test it?

Comment: Yes, i finally tested it this morning. In the end I think this is added complexity. So instead I chose the approach in the answer above. Thanks for your help, at least I know there are other ways for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I decided to use variable groups in the library tab :

[image]

And then in my Yaml pipeline I simply reference the right group according to the stage that is running:

```
variables: 
- group: 'dev'
```